# JSON to javaScript array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a problem handling JSON data within JavaScript, specifically in regards to using the data as an array and accessing and iterating through individual values.  The JSON file is structured as follows:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "place" , "lat" , "long" , "page" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "place": { "type": "literal" , "value": "Building A" } ,
        "lat": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "10.3456" } ,
        "long": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "-1.2345" } ,
        "page": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www.example.com/a.html" }
      } ,
      {
        "place": { "type": "literal" , "value": "Building B" } ,
        "lat": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "11.3456" } ,
        "long": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "-2.2345" } ,
        "page": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www.example.com/b.html" }
      } ,
      {
        "place": { "type": "literal" , "value": "Building C" } ,
        "lat": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "12.3456" } ,
        "long": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "-3.2345" } ,
        "page": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www.example.com/c.html" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to be able to convert this into a JavaScript array as follows in order that I can iterate through it and pull out the values for each location in order:

```
var locations = [
        ['Building A',10.3456,-1.2345,'http://www.example.com/a.html'],
        ['Building B',11.3456,-2.2345,'http://www.example.com/b.html'],
        ['Building C',12.3456,-3.2345,'http://www.example.com/c.html']
];
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?  I have tried the following, but it picks up the "type" within the JSON, rather than just the value:

```
$.each(JSONObject.results.bindings, function(i, object) {
    $.each(object, function(property, object) {
        $.each(object, function(property, value) {
              value;
        });
    });
});
```

Any help, suggestions, advice or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var locations = [];
$.each(JSONObject.results.bindings, function(i, obj) {
    locations.push([obj.place.value, obj.lat.value, obj.long.value, obj.page.value]);
});
```

Iterate through `bindings`, and put the properties `place.value`, `lat.value`, `long.value` and `page.value` from each element into an array, then add this array to `locations`.

Your current code uses `object` twice, as well as `property`, thus overwriting those variables. You should use unique variable names in nested loops to be able to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 5):

for a pure Javascript very similar to the accepted answer (which I like)

I like to use a negative while loop for speed (over a traditional for loop) when I have a defined length.  This is likely faster than the jQuery answer also.

```
var i = JSONObject.results.bindings.length;
var locations = [];
while (i--) {
    t = JSONObject.results.bindings[i];
    locations.push([t.place.value, t.lat.value, t.long.value, t.page.value]);
};
//now show the places
var c = locations.length;
while (c--) {
    alert(locations[c][0]);
};
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/JH7LR/

EDIT: Updated the example fiddle to stick the stuff in a div.
(uses a little jQuery which was not part of the OP question so it is "added material" makes an assumption you have a `<div id='holdem'></div>` somewhere.

```
$(locations).each(function(i) {
    $('#holdem').prepend("<div>" + $(this)[0] + " Is at:" + this + "</div>");
});
```

For some fun I updated the fiddle to show the building name as a link to the building page: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/JH7LR/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
loc=json.results.bindings;
tempar1=[];
tempar2=[];

for (i=0;i<loc.length;i++) {     
    for (prop in loc[i]) {
        temp=loc[i][prop].value;
        tempar1.push(temp);
    }
    tempar2.push(tempar1);
    tempar1=[];
}
```

Where json is equal to the Json Object

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
for (i=0;i<JSONObject.results.bindings.length;i++)

{newObject = JSONObject.results.bindings;
somethingelse = newObject[i].place.type;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this.

```
var locations = [];
JSONObject.results.bindings.forEach(function(binding) {
    locations.push([
        binding.place.value,
        binding.lat.value,
        binding.long.value,
        binding.page.value
    ]);
});
```