# How to convert json object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I need to create an array from JSON data in node.js. I dont want to use jquery selector for this.

```
data = { List : ['1' , '2' , '3'] }
```

I am sending this data in the ajax call (POST).
At the server end receving is:-

```
reqArray = req.param('List');
reqArray contains:- ['1' ,'2' ,'3']
```

I need this `reqArray` as an input to `$in` in `mongoDb` ,where it takes array as as input.

In the format `[1 ,2 , 3]` please suggest a way of doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518313/convert-json-to-array-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try using the map function:

```
var numberArray = reqArray.map(function(element) {
    return +element;
});
```

The `+` will automatically convert it to a number.

Like correctly commented it is even better to use:

```
var numberArray = reqArray.map(Number);
```

Comment: Simpler: `['1','2','3'].map(Number); //=> [1,2,3]`

Comment: if its not a number , lets suppose some alphaNum , then how to do this ?

Comment: The real question is, how do you want to handle `NaN` values?

Comment: actually its going to be an _id for mongodb collection... using an array of this _ids as in input to $in in finding all the list from the collection in one go.

Comment: Is an `_id` always an integer? If not, the whole question makes no sense. If it is, you need some error handling, when an element of the array is not a number.