# how to convert a JSon object to an array in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I am returning array as

```
$array = array {
         'id' => 1,
         'name'=>krishna,
}
echo json_encode($array);
exit;
```

from an ajax call

How can I convert this json value to java script array?

This is my actual data

```
var data = [{
   "candidate_notes_id":"1",
    "candidate_id":"38",
    "subject":"test",
    "description":"t‌estestsete\netestes\n\n\nsteetet",
    "private":"0",
    "created_date":"2012-09-14 11:55:13",
    "updated_date":"2012-09-14 11:55:13",
    "updated_by":"admin"
  }] 

 var newArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
 alert(newArray);
 return false;
```

result :

```
                      var newArray = JSON.stringify(data);
          var date_split = newArray.substr(1,newArray.length-2);
          var newData = date_split.replace('\n','<br>');
          var newArray = $.parseJSON(newData); 
          alert(newArray.candidate_notes_id);
          alert(newArray.candidate_id);
          alert(newArray.subject);
          alert(newArray.description);
```

Comment: Why don't you mind to ask Google exactly the same question? You don't know what Google is? [how can i convert this json value to java script array](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=ru&tab=ww&authuser=0#hl=ru&safe=off&authuser=0&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+can+i+convert+this+json+value+to+java+script+array&oq=how+can+i+convert+this+json+value+to+java+script+array&gs_l=hp.3...1099.1099.0.1934.1.1.0.0.0.0.214.214.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.1j2.48sKiECMHuA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b9d969de151e492a&biw=1273&bih=787)

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to have a Javascript array [1, "krishna"] or a Javascript object {id:1, name: "krishna"} ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you show the function from which you return false?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can use `jQuery.parseJSON(YOUR_AJAX_RESPONSE_DATA);` which will convert json to JS object

Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: This is my actual data 
var data = [{"candidate_notes_id":"1","candidate_id":"38","subject":"test","description":"testestsete\netestes\n\n\nsteetet","private":"0","created_date":"2012-09-14 11:55:13","updated_date":"2012-09-14 11:55:13","updated_by":"admin"}]
 var newArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);                     
  alert(newArray);return false;                                                                The Return value is null

Comment: Control characters like \n need to be escaped. Look at your error console. "Bad control character in string literal". The `\n` have to be `\\n`

Comment: This is the ajax response?

`{"candidate_notes_id":"1","candidate_id":"38","subject":"test","description":"t‌​estestsete\netestes\n\n\nsteetet","private":"0","created_date":"2012-09-14 11:55:13","updated_date":"2012-09-14 11:55:13","updated_by":"admin"}`

Comment: I think you trying to get as array but they are in object. I modified your code and here it is, http://jsfiddle.net/25sjh/

Also you need to escape `\n` as `\\n`. I think you can do this in PHP side.

Comment: Ok. If my answer help you can set it as correct answer and give rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at an answered question ...

You will find how to convert a json to an array.

[JSON to javaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872832/json-to-javascript-array)

```
var array = [];
$.each(JSONObject, function(i, obj) {
    array.push([obj.id.value, obj.name.value]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it using

```
obj = JSON.parse(responseData); // replace `responseData` with your XHR response variable name
```

in your success callback function. Then convert it an array as follows

```
var myArray=[];
myArray[0]=obj.id;
myArray[1]=obj.name;
```

**but first of all your**

```
$array = array {
    'id' => 1,
    'name'=>krishna,
};
```

should be

```
$array = array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name'=>'krishna'
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Stq2k/1/).

Comment: When i am using JSON.parse() its through the error like                                                                    SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: And 'krishna' should be quotes, assuming it's not a constant.