# Convert Json data to specific array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm receiving a response from json in the below format

```
["user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user5", "user6", "user7"]
```

and i need to convert it into the below Format

```
    [
     { id: 'user0', text: 'user1'},
     { id: 'user1', text: 'user2'},
     { id: 'user2', text: 'user3'},
     { id: 'user3', text: 'user4'},
     { id: 'user5', text: 'user5'},
     { id: 'user6', text: 'user6' },
     { id: 'user7', text: 'user7' }
    ];
```

How this can be achieved in javascript.

Comment: What have you tried? Read the FAQ plz: it clearly states that a good question shows the OP has put some effort into it

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where are you stuck? If you don't post your code we cannot help you with it.

Comment: Did you try anything?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872832/json-to-javascript-array ,Ithink it contain your need

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop should do what you need:

```
var myArray = ["user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user5", "user6", "user7"];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {
    var newItem = {id : myArray[i], text: "user" + (i +1)};
    newArray.push(newItem);
}
```

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/eVQWS/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
var arr = ["user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user5", "user6", "user7"],
    result = arr.map(function(e, i, a) {
        return { id: e, text: i < a.length - 1 ? a[i+1] : e };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Please check for [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) at **MDN** and use [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern browser I would use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map).

```
var array = ["user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user5", "user6", "user7"];

var newArray = array.map(function(item) {
    return {id: item, text: item};
})
```

If you have to support old browsers with no ES5 supports, I would use a shim – usually I shim all the [ES5 methods](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), but you can also implement only the one you need, an implementation example is in the docs.

Just to know, in the ES6 – and Firefox Nightly that already support the new fat array syntax – you could actually have:

```
var array = ["user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user5", "user6", "user7"];

var newArray = array.map(item => ({id: item, text: item}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var a = ["user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user5", "user6", "user7"]
    var array = [];

    for(var i =0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        var temp = new Object();
        temp.id= a[i];
        temp.text = a[i];
        array.push(temp);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(array));
    }

var requiredString = JSON.stringify(array);
alert(requiredString.replace(/"id"/g, 'id').replace(/"text"/g,text));
```

Comment: Thanks @PranitG!! The output for above is
[{"id":"user0","text":"user0"},{"id":"user1","text":"user1"},{"id":"user2","text":"user2"},{"id":"user3","text":"user3"},{"id":"user5","text":"user5"},{"id":"user6","text":"user6"},{"id":"user7","text":"user7"}]

i want id and text without quotes, would that be possible.

Comment: yes.
try it
var requiredString = JSON.stringify(array);
alert(requiredString.replace(/"id"/g, 'id').replace(/"text"/g,text));

Comment: Please see my edit in answer. You need to use `replace` function

Comment: @rohitj: The quotation marks are just part of the representation of the data. They are not actually part of the data itself. If you want the data as JSON, then the quotation marks are *required*. Also don't forget to accept an answer.

Comment: You can achieve both the things. If you want quotation do not use `replace` which i mentioned. If you want quotation use 'replace' like indicated. Still it is better to use it with quotation because it is default formatting for JSON