# Array to json data transformation with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here I have this code and variable polygon:

```
 var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
          var bermudaTriangle;
          var directionsPoints;
          var example;
          var rez;

    function initialize() {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom:7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: chicago
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }

    function calcRoute() {
      var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
      var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
      var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          directionsPoints= response.routes[0].overview_path;

//In this format I must transform directionsPoints
          example= [[{"X":72,"Y":59.45},{"X":136,"Y":66},{"X":170,"Y":99},{"X":171,"Y":114},{"X":183,"Y":125},{"X":218,"Y":144},{"X":218,"Y":165},{"X":226,"Y":193},{"X":254,"Y":195},{"X":283,"Y":195},{"X":292,"Y":202},{"X":325,"Y":213},{"X":341,"Y":234},{"X":397,"Y":245},{"X":417,"Y":248}]]; 
          function draw() {
      var polygons = response.routes[0].overview_path; 
      var scale = 100;
      reverse_copy(polygons);
      polygons = scaleup(polygons, scale);
      var cpr = new ClipperLib.Clipper();
      var delta = 25;
      var joinType = ClipperLib.JoinType.jtRound;
      var miterLimit = 2;
      var AutoFix = true;
      var svg, offsetted_polygon,
      cont = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
      offsetted_polygon = cpr.OffsetPolygons(polygons, delta * scale, joinType, miterLimit, AutoFix);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(offsetted_polygon));


      svg = polys2path(offsetted_polygon, scale);
            rez= polys2path(offsetted_polygon, scale);


             bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: svg,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });

      bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

    }
    // helper function to scale up polygon coordinates
    function scaleup(poly, scale) {
      var i, j;
      if (!scale) scale = 1;
      for(i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < poly[i].length; j++) {
          poly[i][j].lb *= scale;
          poly[i][j].mb *= scale;
        }
      }
      return poly;
    }

    // converts polygons to SVG path string
    function polys2path (poly, scale) {
      var path = "", i, j;
      if (!scale) scale = 1;
      for(i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < poly[i].length; j++){
          if (!j) path += "M";
          else path += "L";
          path += (poly[i][j].lb / scale) + ", " + (poly[i][j].mb / scale);
        }
        path += "Z";
      }
      return path;
    }

    function reverse_copy(poly) {
        // Make reverse copy of polygons = convert polyline to a 'flat' polygon ...
      var k, klen = poly.length, len, j; 
      for (k = 0; k < klen; k++) {
        len = poly[k].length;
        poly[k].length = len * 2 - 2;
        for (j = 1; j <= len - 2; j++) {
          poly[k][len - 1 + j] = {
            lb: poly[k][len - 1 - j].lb,
            mb: poly[k][len - 1 - j].mb
          }
        }
      }
    }


        }
      });
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So as you see in the code above I must transform variable

```
 var polygons = response.routes[0].overview_path;
```

into format example:

```
  example= [[{"X":72,"Y":59.45},{"X":136,"Y":66},{"X":170,"Y":99},{"X":171,"Y":114},{"X":183,"Y":125},{"X":218,"Y":144},{"X":218,"Y":165},{"X":226,"Y":193},{"X":254,"Y":195},{"X":283,"Y":195},{"X":292,"Y":202},{"X":325,"Y":213},{"X":341,"Y":234},{"X":397,"Y":245},{"X":417,"Y":248}]];
```

SO how I can transform `polygons` variable to be like `example`

Here is complete code: http://jsbin.com/uTATePe/21/edit

Comment: There's an error in your code. `draw` is not being called - I assume because it's a nested function...

Comment: how I can solve that?

Comment: You should add `draw();` somewhere in the code to execute function otherwise it will not work. You also should do some code formatting **before** posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) examples and [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6872874/1418878) for pushing into `example` array.

Comment: what is inside polygons you can see with console.log(primer) so please see what is exactly the code